# Page number in title page

Tags: numbering, page

I want to add page number from 531 to 536 in my latex IEEE conference template. But page number appearing from page 2 i.e. 532.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\makeatletter
\let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
    % for all pages except the first
    \def\ps@headings{%
        \old@ps@headings%
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    }%
    % for the first page
    \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
        \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    }%
    \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{ 2020 IEEE International Conference on Computation, Automation and Knowledge Management (ICCAKM)
}


%%footer
%\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
%\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{
%   \setbox0=\hbox{#3}
%   \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{ \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\vtop{{\null}\makebox[0pt][c]{#3}}}
%   }
%}
%\placetextbox{.23}{0.055}{\small{978-1-5386-8007-0/19/\$31.00~\copyright 2019 IEEE}}




\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}




%
%\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
%\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{
%   \setbox0=\hbox{#3}
%   \AddToShipoutPictureFG{ \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\vtop{{\null}\makebox[0pt][c]{#3}}}
%   }
%}
%\placetextbox{.2}{0.055}{978-1-4799-5522-0/15/\$31.00~\copyright 2015 IEEE}


\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-7281-0666-3/20/\$31.00~\copyright~2020
        IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \setcounter{page}{531} 

\begin{document}

\title{Performance Analysis of Physically
    Unclonable Function Based on Voltage Divider Arrays}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Sumit Chaudhary$^{1}$}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Electronics and Communication} \\
        \textit{MNIT Jaipur, India}\\
        2016pev5165@mnit.ac.in}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Chitrakant Sahu$^{2}$}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Electronics and Communication} \\
        \textit{MNIT Jaipur, India}\\
        chitrakant.ece@mnit.ac.in}}
 \maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\@oddfoot` from `maketitle` definition, I have pasted below updated macro:

`\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{\def\@evenfoot{}%
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference
   \def\@oddhead{}%
   \def\@evenhead{}%
\else
   \def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\scriptsize\leftmark \hfil \thepage}%
   \def\@evenhead{\scriptsize\thepage \hfil \leftmark\hbox{}}%
\fi
\ifCLASSOPTIONdraftcls
   \def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\scriptsize\leftmark \hfil \thepage}%
   \def\@evenhead{\scriptsize\thepage \hfil \leftmark\hbox{}}%
   \ifCLASSOPTIONdraftclsnofoot\else
      \def\@oddfoot{\scriptsize \@date\hfil DRAFT}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\scriptsize DRAFT\hfil \@date}%
   \fi
\else
   % all non-draft mode footers
   \if@IEEEusingpubid
      % for title pages that are using a pubid
      % do not repeat pubid if using peer review option
      \ifCLASSOPTIONpeerreview
      \else
         \footskip 0pt%
         \ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
           \def\@oddfoot{\hss\normalfont\scriptsize\raisebox{-1.5\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip}[0ex][0ex]{\@IEEEpubid}\hss}%
           \def\@evenfoot{\hss\normalfont\scriptsize\raisebox{-1.5\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip}[0ex][0ex]{\@IEEEpubid}\hss}%
         \else
           \def\@oddfoot{\hss\normalfont\footnotesize\raisebox{1.5ex}[1.5ex]{\@IEEEpubid}\hss}%
           \def\@evenfoot{\hss\normalfont\footnotesize\raisebox{1.5ex}[1.5ex]{\@IEEEpubid}\hss}%
         \fi
      \fi
   \fi
\fi}
\makeatother`

Use this macro above `\begin{document}`

Comment: i have updated the macro and it is compiling properly but first page number is still not coming in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated in your `IEEEtitlepagestyle` macro

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
    % for all pages except the first
    \def\ps@headings{%
        \old@ps@headings%
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    }%
    % for the first page
    \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
        \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
        \def\@oddfoot{\strut\hfill\thepage\hfill\strut}
        \def\@evenfoot{\strut\hfill\thepage\hfill\strut}
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    }%
    \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{ 2020 IEEE International Conference on Computation, Automation and Knowledge Management (ICCAKM)}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-7281-0666-3/20/\$31.00~\copyright~2020
        IEEE \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{531}

\begin{document}

\title{Performance Analysis of Physically
    Unclonable Function Based on Voltage Divider Arrays}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Sumit Chaudhary$^{1}$}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Electronics and Communication} \\
        \textit{MNIT Jaipur, India}\\
        2016pev5165@mnit.ac.in}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Chitrakant Sahu$^{2}$}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Electronics and Communication} \\
        \textit{MNIT Jaipur, India}\\
        chitrakant.ece@mnit.ac.in}}
 \maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]