# First page number is missing in document

Tags: page-numbering, page

I want to add page number from 531-536 in my LaTeX IEEE conference template. But page number appearing from page 2 i.e. 532. Could anyone help me?

```latex
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{531}
```

Comment: i have also added footer in my document

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to add page number from 531-536 in my latex IEEE conference template. But page number appearing from page 2 i.e. 532. Could anyone help me?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524587/i-want-to-add-page-number-from-531-536-in-my-latex-ieee-conference-template-but)